# Compare only values of arrays and get difference

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two arrays like below;

```
array1 =  {
           [0]=> 'A'
           [1]=> 'B'
           [2]=> 'C'
          }

array2 =  {
           [0]=> 'B'
           [1]=> 'C'
           [2]=> 'D'
          }
```

I want to compare these two arrays and get the difference.
What I need return is like this;

```
 result =  {
            [0]=> 'A'
            [1]=> 'D'
           }
```

I thought I could use `array_diff`, but it compares key AND value as a pair. I want to compare ONLY values.
How can I do that?

Comment: You want it in `php` or `js`?

Comment: I wanna do it in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work -

```
array_diff(array_merge($a, $b), array_intersect($a, $b))
```

Checking difference between all merged and all common.

Comment: Wow that worked!! Thank you so much for the super fast response!